# Can't receive value from another class on XNA Framework C#

Tags: xna

I have several classes on my  project: Game1(main class(default)), Animation and Enemy:

```
public class Animation 
{
      public  int currentFrameHit;
      public Animation ()
      {
      }

      public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
      {
          timeElapsedHit += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
          if (timeElapsedHit > 100)
          {
              timeElapsedHit = 0;
              currentFrameHit = (currentFrameHit + 1) % 9;
          }
       }
}
```

How can i get value from variable in Animation class?
In Enemy class i can't receive this value from Animation. I tried that:

```
   Animation animation = new Animation();
   Console.WriteLine(animation.currentFrameHit);
```

But i'm getting null, however in main class Game1 i receive right values with same code.

Comment: if you want to use a variable in a class *without making an instance of that class*, the variable must be `static`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've changed public  int currentFrameHit; to
public static int currentFrameHit and called from a Animation class Animation.currentFrameHit and gave value. It's fine now, but on my example a made an instance of that class: Animation animation = new Animation();
   Console.WriteLine(animation.currentFrameHit); or you mean  what i should have to make constructor? Anyway that issue's solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're making a `new Animation()` without assigning it to anything. so it'll keep returning it's default value.

So far there isn't enough information given on what the number should be though. Do you have the Animation() class inside the Enemy Class, or do you find the Enemy Class within Animation()?

Comment: I try to find inside the Enemy Class. But also in the Animation Class i have a constructor
  
public Animation

(Texture2D playerTextureHit, Vector2 playerPositionHit, Rectangle playerRectangleHit)
        {
            this.playerTextureHit = playerTextureHit;
            this.playerRectangleHit = playerRectangleHit;
            this.playerPositionHit = playerPositionHit;
            
        }
and empty  public Animation ()
      {
      }

Comment: I don't know how your code works, but try using the constructor animation instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference to an existing animation value.

Create an instance in your desire class (here it is Game1) and don't forget to make it public.

```
public static Animation animationGame1 = new Animation();
```

Then in your second class:

In LoadContent(): reference it to Game1's variable:

```
Animation animationNewClass = Game1.animationGame1;
```

In Update(): do what you want to achieve:

```
Console.WriteLine(animationNewClass.currentFrameHit);
```

Hope this helps.